# how to print link in file and later using it to reference terms in another file in java

Tags: java, information-retrieval

1. You need to write a program invert to do the index construction. The input to the program is the document collection. The output includes two files - a dictionary file and a postings lists file. Each entry in the dictionary should include a term, its document frequency and a link to its postings list. You should use a proper data structure to build the dictionary (e.g. hashing or search tree or others). The structure should be easy for random lookup and insertion of new terms. All the terms should be sorted in alphabetical order. Postings list for each term should include postings for all documents the term occurs in (in the order of document ID), and the information saved in a posting includes document ID, term frequency in the document, and positions of all occurrences of the term in the document.

i have created both files and read each term and saved them in this hashmap

```
    private static HashMap<dictionary, List<postings>> index = new HashMap<dictionary , List<postings>>();
```

how do i create this link because for the second program i run it with both txt files that are created from invert.java
my dictionary.txt only consists of term and ferquency and how do i create this link?

Comment: This is too long. I would isolate the problem a bit more so people can digest your question better.

Comment: as requested i have isolated the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost a database style problem, where you have entities represented by keys. So, for each major class you create to represent the items at hand, think of what will be their index.

Assuming you have something like:

```
// use Jackson to read/write your data files in Json format
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

public class Inverter {
    private JsonFileWriter fileWriter;

    /*
     * Don't use HashMap since it isn't sorted
     */
    Map<String, TermMetadata> dictionary = new HashMap<>();

    public List<File> invert(final Collection<Document> documents) {
    }

    public void writeDictionation() {
        fileWriter.write(dictionary);
    }

    public void writePostings() {
        fileWriter.write(postings);
    }
}

public class Document {
    /**
     * Index is the documentId
     */
    int documentId;

    // other attributes ...
}

public class TermMetadata {
    /*
     * Index on the term
     */
    String term;
    int documentFrequency;
    List<int> postingsIds;
}

public class Posting {
    /**
     * Index on the posting id
     */
    int postingId;
    int documentId;
    int termFrequency;
    List<int> positions;
}
```

Then wherever you read back the values from the text files, you can join on the indexes.

So, the `List<int> postingIds` on `TermMetadata` would be used to refer to  Postings, by their `postingId` key.

I think ideally, this would be implemented as a Java front-end to a database. However, since you are using files instead, I'd suggest to use some standard serialization mechanism like Json to store the object representations.

Using Jackson `ObjectMapper`, when you go to read the postings file, you'll have a big list of `Posting` objects and can call `getPostingId()` and then join that up with the info in `TermMetadata`'s `List<int>` postingIds`.